# JavaScript form opens "infinite" tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, tabs

I have a script which gets a form with fields filled by itself, and I got a code that submits the form automatically every x second(s).

The problem is that I added this attribute (target="_blank") to the form, but the form kept on executing the code and creating a new tab infinitely.

I want my script to create a new tab for processing the form and the second time my script executes, to use the same tab to refresh the processing page.

Can I do that in JavaScript?

```
<form target="_blank" name="myForm" id="myForm" action="process.asp" method="post">
        field 1:<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" /><br>
        field 2:<input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" /><br>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript"> // code which executes the submit of form operation 
            window.onload=function(){
                var auto = setTimeout(function(){ autoRefresh(); }, 100);

                function submitform(){
                    document.forms["myForm"].submit();
                }

                function autoRefresh(){
                    clearTimeout(auto);
                    auto = setTimeout(function(){ submitform(); autoRefresh(); }, 10000);
                }
            }
    </script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try with this code (Using Ajax). It will help you with ajax and it not open any new tab and help to submit form with Last Updated Date and Time.

It work on My Base.

Please Try it with Your Code.

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form target="_self" name="myForm" id="myForm" action="process.asp" method="post">
            field 1:<input type="text" name="field1" id="F1" />
            <br>
            field 2:<input type="text" name="field2" id="F2" />
            <br>
            <p id="LastDt"></p>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript"> // code which executes the submit of form operation 
            window.onload = function () {
                var auto = setTimeout(function () {
                    autoRefresh();
                }, 100);

                function submitform() {

                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    {
                        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("LastDt").innerHTML = "Last Update : " + new Date();
                        }
                    };

                    // It send data on process.asp (silently).
                    xmlhttp.open("POST", "process.asp?field1=" + document.getElementById("F1").value + "&field2=" + document.getElementById("F2").value , true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }


                function autoRefresh() {
                    clearTimeout(auto);
                    auto = setTimeout(function () {
                        submitform();
                    }, 10000);
                }
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add same form in `process.asp` and after the first submit opens the new tab...use [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to pass data to other tab and have it submit from there.

Or you could store the data in localStorage and use [storage events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/storage) in `process.asp` to listen for updates and post the data